# How can I script data entry on a website with a captcha?

Tags: browser, script, web, captcha

I have several thousand records stored in a text file that I need to enter into a (JavaScript-based) web page, one record at a time. After I enter each record I need to parse the returned data and then go back to the initial page. The problem is that the web page uses a Captcha as part of its login sequence (only one Captcha, then I'll stay logged in until it times out due to inactivity). I'd obviously like to be able to script this, but due to the Captcha, it seems as if using Lynx is out of the question. It's something I'll be doing several times a year, so IMO the initial effort would be worthwhile.

Any way I can do this? I'm very comfortable with Perl and shell scripting, but would be willing to learn another scripting language if necessary. Preferred platform is Windows, but I of course can run it under Cygwin or Linux for Windows (and if absolutely necessary can dig up a Mac to use instead).

Answer (score 2):

There's no reliable way to beat CAPTCHA without humans consistently without the presence of an OCR. It seems that you are trying to do this through pure chance. Think of this from a probabilistic standpoint and you will soon realize this is near impossible odds, and even worse ones to replicate consistently.

If you are trying to just do this once then stay logged and simulate human activity then this is realistic. Look into the library *Selenium* which can be used with a number of programming languages. I think you can do it in Perl but would probably be easier to do in Python instead.

Comment: Yes, I just want to do it once - IOW, have it show me the CAPTCHA, I enter the required info, then let it get on with the work. I'll take a look at Selenium, th anks.

Comment: The easiest way would be with a sleep timer within your python script. You could pause the script for however long, maybe 3 minutes, which would give you time to enter your CAPTCHA. At the end of your allotted time, the script would continue to run as usual. For information of the sleep function in Python look at the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python

Comment: @Swechsler Selenium is a good choice, but just as an FYI, if you Google something like "[captcha python](https://www.google.com/search?q=captcha+python)", there are numerous tutorials on using Python to solve (at least simple) captchas.

Comment: The Captchas involved are of the type "click on the store fronts" in a 4x4 array.

Just had another look;the captcha is inconsistent; sometimes it comes up, sometimes it doesn't, but it's always during the login sequence.